# 3ds Max error dialog: "Instancing not supported for this action"

Tags: 3dsmax

"Instancing not supported for this action” is the dialog I get. My favorite part is that, according to google and yahoo, apparently i am the only person in the history of mankind to experience these words together in this order, let along get this message from Max. Thanks, autodesk, for putting this dialog in special for me!

So I’ve created my model (nws) and was setting up a Skin Wrap. Selected "Face Deformation", added the base-skin for weight, checked “weight all points”. . . clicked “convert to skin” and got that dialog.

My model doesn’t have a whole lot of elements to it, I had a left and right appendage that came from a base model (skyrim). so, i did a clone>copy of all 3 of my elements, just to be sure nothing was instanced… and VOILA! Same error message. the only other elements are an imported NIF mesh and skeleton.

Any idea where this is coming from or how I can make it go away so that I can export my mesh?

Comment: i ever had this problem,try to verify if the mesh over which you try to set up the skin wrap is not an instance.

Comment: Did you ask Autodesk?

Comment: @al_01 please read the entire OP.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou I have 2 answers to that question: 1) I posted to their official forums. 2) have you ever tried to ask autodesk anything? It ends quietly.

Comment: @monsto Haha, well, I'm sorry for you. Maybe you should try sending them the smallest file possible that reproduces the problem, that usually helps in solving bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved this already, but for anyone who encounters this problem. It is because you applied the skin wrap to more than one object at a time. Convert to skin does not support this, so you'd need to do it for every object individually.